# arangodb data definition execution issue

Tags: database, docker, kubernetes, command-line-interface, arangodb

I am trying to execute below command in arangodb kubernetes based container, where arango "Version 0.13.7, build bdac926" is running.

command which tried from my end :

**arangodb-ddl-exec-cli**.jar -input_file arangodb_ddl.json -db_url "http://11.22.3.5:32532" -username root -password XXXX**

while executing above command getting belwo error:

**bash: arangodb-ddl-exec-cli-1.0.0-RELEASE-standalone.jar: command not found**

My specification:

Docker - 18.03.1-ce

Kubernetes - v1.12.0

Kubernetes arangodb service port ( Type: Nodeport ) - 8529:32532/TCP

please let me know how to resolve it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to run a JAR file inside the container? 
If yes then you should first install the JRE in the container (for example by adding it in Dockerfile or at the moment from the inside of the container). 
First check if Java is installed using `java --version` 
If it is not there  - install it. When you have it run:
`java -jar arangodb-ddl-exec-cli.jar` and rest of your arguments.

Hope this helps.